# How to get data and load it into a view without page refresh from button click?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

I would like to click a button and have it pull data and then load it into a view and have it displayed on the page without a page refresh. I'm understanding that I need to use AJAX to do this. I am completely new to AJAX. How do I set this up with my views/controller/javascript?

I have a button `<a id="pick-btn">Pick</a>` and a containing div `<div id="pick-list"></div>`. How do I get the data I need through my controller and have it display the data into a view which is displayed in that containing div?

Here is my controller function:

```
public function pick_list()
{
    $data['list'] = $this->model->get_stuff();

    $this->load->view('someview', $data, TRUE);
}
```

And here is my javascript to handle the button click event

```
$('a#pick-btn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'controller/function',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (html) {
          $('#pick-list').html(html);
        }
    });
});
```

However, this isn't doing anything. What am I doing wrong? Please help!

UPDATE:

Ok, I got this to work by testing with some static URLs (which was my problem, JavaScript wasnt getting the URLs to the controller/method and view file dynamically for some reason). Now when I load the view, it loads everything except for when it hits this `form_input()`. And basically any part with php it cannot load and tells me that form_input() is an undefined function, blah blah blah. Why won't it recognize that function and all the other php variables?

Comment: are you getting some errors?

Comment: if its html you are loading then the load function might be better -- http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I'm not getting any errors

Comment: maybe it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253470/how-to-codeigniter-ajax-get-data

Comment: Check inside `console` of `browser`. You will get an `error` if there.

Comment: change your url  in javascript controller/function to yourconrollername /pick_list